# Create a pandas table

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

In using pandas, how can I display a table similar to this one.

I think I have to use a dataframe similar to `df = pandas.DataFrame(results)` and display it with `display.display(df)` but from there I don't know what to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass in a dictionary as `data` when you use [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = {
...     'Algothime': ['KNN', 'SVM', 'MLP'],
...     'Param. 1': ['-', '-', '-'],
...     'Param. 2': ['-', '-', '-'],
...     'Plage param. 1': ['-', '-', '-'],
...     'Plage param. 2': ['-', '-', '-'],
... }
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df
  Algothime Param. 1 Param. 2 Plage param. 1 Plage param. 2
0       KNN        -        -              -              -
1       SVM        -        -              -              -
2       MLP        -        -              -              -
```

If you want that specific style you can use [**Google Colab**](https://colab.research.google.com/) or something similar if you don't have **[Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/install)** installed locally:
[image: Colab Example]

Answer (score 2):

I recommend looking at this [10 min tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html).

To answer your question

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Algotihme', 'Param. 1', 'Param. 2', 'Plage Param. 1', 'Plage Param. 2' ])
df['Algotihme'] = ['KNN', 'SVM', 'MLP']
df
```

To display the dataframe simply put 'df' in an empty cell in Jupyter Notebook and run it

Answer (score 1):

In an interactive environment, you can always display a Pandas dataframe (or any other Python object) just by typing its name as its own command, e.g., type `df` on its own line.

However, the appearance of the table will differ depending on the environment you are using. Pandas has two ways of showing tables: plain text and HTML. The one you showed in your question is the HTML version.

If you use Python in an ordinary text terminal, you will get the plain text version. The easiest way to see the HTML version is by using one of these:

- a Jupyter notebook, can be local or on [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb) or [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com/), etc.
- a Jupyter qtconsole
- Atom editor with the Hydrogen plugin
- Visual Studio Code editor with the Python plugin

If you are using one of these, whenever you display a dataframe (type `df` on its own line), you will automatically see the HTML version. If you use the same command in a plain-text terminal, you will get the plain-text version.

**UPDATE.** As an example using Google Colab:

1. Go to [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb).
2. Login if needed.
3. Read the Introduction notebook (recommended).
4. Choose File > "New notebook" to create and open a new notebook.
5. Enter the commands from [Shash Sinha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64506399/3830997), all in one cell:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
    'Algorithme': ['KNN', 'SVM','MLP'],
    'Param. 1': ['-', '-', '-'],
    'Param. 2': ['-', '-', '-'],
    'Plage param. 1': ['-', '-', '-'],
    'Plage param. 2': ['-', '-', '-']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

6. Press the "play" button (gray triangle) or press Shift-Enter or Shift-Return.
7. Jupyter will run the code in the cell and then show you an HTML table like the one in your question.
8. You can also put `df` in its own cell and run that later to see the dataframe again.

Comment: Are you up to give me an example? I am using colab

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([('KNN', '-', '-', '-', '-'),
                   ('SVM', '-', '-', '-', '-'),
                   ('gold', '-', '-', '-', '-')],
                    columns=('Algotihme', 'Param. 1', 'Param. 2', 'Plage Param. 1', 'Plage Param. 2' ))
```