# Creating a table to show averages on python

Tags: python, pandas, economics

I am trying to figure out the code to generate a table that shows average retail price, average wholesale price, and the average market share. I am being asked to use `df` and `groupby`
]

The image shows the gas stations I am looking at and lists the name, ID, Address, Latitude, Longitude, date, Price, Wholesale, Tax, mkshare, and brand.

[image]

Comment: What's your question?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is my first time using python so I am trying to create a code to make a table. I haven't tried anything yet because I am not sure where to start

Comment: Hello! It may help us help you to further define your scenario, show sample input data, and give some example/expected output

Comment: Check this question out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64506283/create-a-pandas-table.  This is the reference documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC this is what you want:

```
df.groupby("Name")[["Price", "Wholesale", "mkshare"]].mean()
```

Basically, you have to group by the gas stations names, select the necessary columns and get the mean of them.

It's always good to take a look at the documentation:

- [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
- [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html)