# reads a textile using list as data class objects

Tags: python, text-files, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to solve a program called that reads a file of movie characters and creates a list of the movie characters (as data class objects). However I'm having some problem with it

so far I've come up with this

```
 import os
 from dataclasses import dataclass

 @dataclass
 class objects():
      lst = []
      fname: str = 'starwars.txt'

 lst = []

 char = objects()
 with open(char.fname, "r") as path: # Reads the open file
       for line in path:
   
        x = line[:-1]
        lst.append(x)
 print(lst)
```

but I know I'm doing something wrong because I'm getting this output:

```
['Qui-Gon Jinn, Human, Coruscant', 'Han Solo, Human, Corellia', 'Leia Organa, Human, Alderaan', 'Luke Skywalker, Human, Tatooine', 'Chewbacca, Wookiee, Kashyyyk', 'Cassian Andor, Human, Kenari', 'Jar Jar Binks, Gungan, Naboo', 'Ahsoka Tano, Togruta, Shili', 'Plo Koon, Kel Dor, Dorin', 'Din Djarin, Human, Aq Vetina', 'Cad Bane, Duro, Duros', 'Max Rebo, Ortolan, Orto', 'Boba Fett, Human, Kamino', 'Jabba the Hutt, Hutt, Nal Hutta', 'Rey Skywalker, Human, Jakku']
```

When I'm supposed to get this output

```
Qui-Gon Jinn            Human           Coruscant
Han Solo                Human           Corellia
Leia Organa             Human           Alderaan
Luke Skywalker          Human           Tatooine
Chewbacca               Wookiee         Kashyyyk
Cassian Andor           Human           Kenari
Jar Jar Binks           Gungan          Naboo
Ahsoka Tano             Togruta         Shili
Plo Koon                Kel Dor         Dorin
Din Djarin              Human           Aq Vetina
Cad Bane                Duro            Duros
Max Rebo                Ortolan         Orto
Boba Fett               Human           Kamino
Jabba the Hutt          Hutt            Nal Hutta
Rey Skywalker           Human           Jakku
```

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong or if I'm even reading a file and creating  list of the movie characters as data class objects.I would really appreciate the help

Comment: pandas is a great option for creating tables: [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64506283/create-a-pandas-table)

Comment: @will-wright-eng, OP assignment clearly states list of dataclass objects. Why would they need pandas?

Comment: the text file is comma delimited, pd.read_csv is a simple method of importing that data... I didn't see "assignment" in the question

Comment: You need a dataclass representing single character. Then iterate over file, create a bunch of objects and store them in a list

Comment: @will-wright-eng, task, if you prefer. Although it's pretty clear this is class assignment. And using pandas, just for reading the file is overkill

Answer (score 0):

this works if your txt file is delimited by `\n`:

```py
import os
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class objects():
    lst = []
    fname: str = 'starwars.txt'

lst = []

char = objects()
with open(char.fname, "r") as file: # Reads the open file
    for line in file:
        tmp = line.strip().split('\n')[0].split(',')
        lst.append(tmp)

for line in lst:
    print(f'{line[0]}\t\t{line[1]}\t\t{line[2]}')

import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

```
# print list output
Qui-Gon Jinn         Human       Coruscant
Han Solo         Human       Corellia
Leia Organa      Human       Alderaan
Luke Skywalker       Human       Tatooine
Chewbacca        Wookiee         Kashyyyk
Cassian Andor        Human       Kenari
Jar Jar Binks        Gungan      Naboo
Ahsoka Tano      Togruta         Shili
Plo Koon         Kel Dor         Dorin
Din Djarin       Human       Aq Vetina
Cad Bane         Duro        Duros
Max Rebo         Ortolan         Orto
Boba Fett        Human       Kamino
Jabba the Hutt       Hutt        Nal Hutta
Rey Skywalker        Human       Jakku

# dataframe output
0   1   2
0   Qui-Gon Jinn    Human   Coruscant
1   Han Solo    Human   Corellia
2   Leia Organa Human   Alderaan
3   Luke Skywalker  Human   Tatooine
4   Chewbacca   Wookiee Kashyyyk
5   Cassian Andor   Human   Kenari
6   Jar Jar Binks   Gungan  Naboo
7   Ahsoka Tano Togruta Shili
8   Plo Koon    Kel Dor Dorin
9   Din Djarin  Human   Aq Vetina
10  Cad Bane    Duro    Duros
11  Max Rebo    Ortolan Orto
12  Boba Fett   Human   Kamino
13  Jabba the Hutt  Hutt    Nal Hutta
14  Rey Skywalker   Human   Jakku
```

pandas is a simple and intuitive tool for handling tables

if your txt file isn't dilimited by the `\n` then I would post a data sample to better represent a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

#### if you prefer to do it in an OO fashion...

```py
@dataclass
class character():
    name: str
    species: str
    origin: str
    
lst = []

char = objects()
with open(char.fname, "r") as file: # Reads the open file
    for line in file:
        tmp = line.strip().split('\n')[0].split(',')
        
        individual = character(name = tmp[0], species = tmp[1], origin = tmp[2])
        lst.append(individual)
```

*output*

```
[character(name='Qui-Gon Jinn', species=' Human', origin=' Coruscant'),
 character(name='Han Solo', species=' Human', origin=' Corellia'),
 character(name='Leia Organa', species=' Human', origin=' Alderaan'),
 character(name='Luke Skywalker', species=' Human', origin=' Tatooine'),
 character(name='Chewbacca', species=' Wookiee', origin=' Kashyyyk'),
 character(name='Cassian Andor', species=' Human', origin=' Kenari'),
 character(name='Jar Jar Binks', species=' Gungan', origin=' Naboo'),
 character(name='Ahsoka Tano', species=' Togruta', origin=' Shili'),
 character(name='Plo Koon', species=' Kel Dor', origin=' Dorin'),
 character(name='Din Djarin', species=' Human', origin=' Aq Vetina'),
 character(name='Cad Bane', species=' Duro', origin=' Duros'),
 character(name='Max Rebo', species=' Ortolan', origin=' Orto'),
 character(name='Boba Fett', species=' Human', origin=' Kamino'),
 character(name='Jabba the Hutt', species=' Hutt', origin=' Nal Hutta'),
 character(name='Rey Skywalker', species=' Human', origin=' Jakku')]
```